# Is there a limit to the number of email alerts than can be setup

Tags: email-alert

There are limits on HTML email template size and number of emails sent per day - as per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_email.htm), but is there a restriction on the number of Email Alerts that can be created in an Org?

This would be an Unlimited Edition Org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall any specific limits on how many email alerts you can *configure*, but there are some [limits regarding Workflow Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_workflow.htm) that will limit how many you can practically use.